# which is the best API automation testing & monitoring tool for Microservices

Tags: api, microservices, cypress

I would like to have automation tool where all the API calls can be tested and monitored frequently for microservices projects.
Can we use Cypress for this API automation and POSTMAN for monitoring? Please suggest.

Comment: *which is the best API automation testing & monitoring tool for Microservices* is off-topic for stack overflow.  From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: However, **Can we use Cypress for this API automation and POSTMAN for monitoring?** might be on-topic here.  If you can [edit] your question to clarify the title and also give some a bit more detail about what you are trying to do, you may be able to attract an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use Wirespec https://wirespec.dev

It lets you create APIs that generate responses on custom endpoints. During your product development, you often need to test your clients using consistent data in order to pass UI tests. Wirespec lets you do that. So all your client apps need to do is switch between your testing/staging/production servers to the wirespec endpoint (which can be customized to look identical to your normal endpoints).